# Delay when switching CNAME between elastic beanstalk environments

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've got two environments in my load balanced elastic beanstalk app. One is the actual production environment, and the other is a holding page to be displayed if/when we need to block all access to the production app, or when the app goes down.

We're using Elastic Beanstalk's [CNAME Swap](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.CNAMESwap.html) feature, which is advertised as a 'zero downtime' feature. However, when we've tested this switch, we see a lag between the switch operation and users actually seeing the new environment - it takes up to 2 minutes to switch either way.

Testing with an incognito browser window seems to indicate that it's a per-session thing. Users who had seen one environment tend to stick to that environment in subsequent requests after the switch, but users who first access the app right after the switch see the new environment. We haven't enabled any sticky-session features, and as I understand it, that anyway only affects routing of traffic to instances within a single environment, not between environments.

Does anyone know what causes this delay, and hopefully how to fix it so that the switch is instant for all users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely cause is DNS Caching on your device and/or internet provider. The Swap URL feature is very useful to update versions without downtime (see [Blue Green Deployments](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/BlueGreenDeployment.html)), but it is certainly subject to the "characteristics" of the globally distributed DNS caches..

Comment: This makes sense. I found out today that Chrome has a built in DNS cache, which explains why only incognito tabs get the new page.

I imagined that a single app had a single IP, no matter which environment was 'live' (like a load balancer of load balancers), but I confirmed that the public IP the CNAME points to changes when you swap env urls, and I found some very helpful reading here, which further explains the DNS cache issue - http://www.hudku.com/blog/demystified-zero-downtime-with-amazon/